# repeat a function while loop not end in python

Tags: python, function, repeat

hey guys i was playing around with my small project and i hit this problem on how to repeat a function
i have tried to call the function it self with in the while loop but did not work maybe use another function to do so like calling another function to call this one again

code is as follows:

```
 #this function is to check user and pass that was entered by the user using the inputs function

 def chk(u = str(a[0]), p = int(a[1])):
    while u not in sales_man.keys():
    call this function again
```

Comment: Why are you specifying default values from an unknown object `a` for your parameters? Do you mean `def chk(u, p): ...` followed by a call like `chk(str(a[0]), int(a[1])`, or do you want to take `a` as the argument to `def chk(x): u = str(x[0]); p = int(x[1]); ...`, then call `chk(a)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to implement a simple login you can use a classic infinite loop like:

```
def check_user(user):
    return user in sales_man.keys()


while True:
    # [...] get username in input

    if check_user(username):
        # [...] ok, check password
    else:
        # [...] wrong user
```